# Can't use 'this' in onload property in an ASP.net document

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onload

I'm trying to load my stylesheets asynchronously, as I usually do, but I'm running in to trouble on an ASP.net site I'm working on. I keep getting the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'this' is not a member of 'ASP.tools_controls_homepage_master'.

This is occuring when I try to use an onload value like in the following `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="preload" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
```

I'm not very familiar with how ASP.net works, but i do know this site was written with VB if that matters. Any help getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Is it supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload) on your browser?

Comment: I'm just following instructions from a CSS Tricks article I read on this a while back. I think the idea of the `onload` is to make sure the CSS still loads in browsers that don't support `rel="preload"`. [It doesn't look like preload is very well supported at all yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=preload)

Comment: Check it: https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/a02f2359f3bc50ca7a9c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working the way I wanted with the `OnClientLoad` property, like so:

```
<link rel="preload" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" as="style" OnClientLoad="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
```

Seems to be working properly in every browser.